# log4j2 environment variable substitution not working for filename attribute

Tags: log4j2

I am trying to configure my daily rolling log file with a filename that contains server port number because this is a multi server application and each server will generate it's own log.

I have the following configuration

```
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout
                    pattern="[%d{ISO8601}:$${env:SERVER_PORT}-L1] [th:%t] [%c] [%level] [%logger{36}] - %n[%d{ISO8601}:$${env:SERVER_PORT}-L2]%msg%n"/>
        </Console>
        <RollingFile name="dailyLog" immediateFlush="false" append="true">
            <FileName>logs/rCOI.${env:SERVER_PORT:8090}.log</FileName>
            <FilePattern>logs/rCOI.${env:SERVER_PORT:8090}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log.zip</FilePattern>
            <PatternLayout
                    pattern="[%d{ISO8601}:$${env:SERVER_PORT}-L1] [th:%t] [%c] [%level] [%logger{36}] - %n[%d{ISO8601}:$${env:SERVER_PORT}-L2]%msg%n"/>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true" />
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="5" />
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="debug">
            <AppenderRef ref="dailyLog"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

This produces a log called 
logs/rCOI.${env:SERVER_PORT:8090}.log 
so it's not even using the default.  I am sure that SERVER_PORT is defined and exported because I use it in the application with no issues.

I have tried $${env:SERVER_PORT:8090} and just ${SERVER_PORT} as well.  Nothing is working.

It would be nice to be able to use an environment variable for the logs/ directory as well.